# store development by using Spartacus for front-end,

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am a beginner to Spartacus so I have a few queries in my mind.

Kindly validate my understanding so far with respect to spartacus:

1. I believe, Spartacus framework will expect all CMS component from SAP Commerce. Once spartacus receive a component  from SAP Commerce then it can be customized as per need
2. I have setup the sparatcus storefront and it's up and running. I have followed the steps mentioned in documentation, but now coming to my customization/implementation of my storefront from complete scratch like header/footer banner etc component needs to be created. So how can I go and which files need to be updated? I mean can this be done from SAP Commerce side first (Component) then Applying CSS and JS can done in Spartacus side?

Answer (score 1):

These are brought questions, and not easy to answer with short answers. A few pointers:

1. Not necessarily. You can [adapt other CMS systems](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/), or customise partially regardless of the CMS.
2. You can [customise CSS](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/css-architecture/), [customise CMC components](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/), use outlets to [amend existing DOM](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/outlets/), etc.